# I'm having problems with combining these two codes together:

Tags: discord.js

This is what I have tried: It only executes the first one.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const roleName = message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Owner")
    if (roleName) {
        return message.reply("Pog")
    } else {
        return message.reply("Sorry, an error occured.")
    }
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'youtube') {
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'clear') {
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'mute') {
        client.commands.get('mute').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'unmute') {
        client.commands.get('unmute').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

I'm new to js and I need help with combining these two codes together.
All I want to do is that the person using command needs to heve certan role, so that like members ...
can't use the mute command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, you just want to find the role first and then run an if statement to check if the user has this role before calling `.execute(message, args);`

This can be done like this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'youtube') {
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'clear') {
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'mute') {
        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "Owner")) {
            client.commands.get('mute').execute(message, args);
        } else {
            message.reply("You are unable to use this command");
        }
    } else if (command == 'unmute') {
        if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "Owner")) {
            client.commands.get('unmute').execute(message, args);
        } else {
            message.reply("You are unable to use this command");
        }
    }
});
```

You should avoid having multiple listeners for the same event and just use one. Also, note that there will be no `member` object in `message` if the message was sent in a DM

Comment: It works now and I have to thank you for, how fast you responded to my problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Oh and is there a way you can add multiple roles? Example: Owner, Moderator... ? Anyways thanks for your response.

Comment: You can chain them together like `if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "Owner") && message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "Moderator"))` and this example would check they have the `Owner` and `Moderator` role. If this answer worked please mark it as correct to help other people

Comment: I don't think it worked, for me it only checks for first role and ignores :  && message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name == "Moderator")) However I don't get any errors.

Comment: Are you sure the `&&` is in the right place?

Comment: Yes Im pretty sure its in the right place.